# Damaged jack port - sound only on headphones

Tags: 12.04, sound, headphones

I have damaged jack input and my system thinks I have headphones plugged in. On a Windows machine I was able to manually switch from headphones to speakers permanently.

**How i can do this in Ubuntu ?**

Comment: I think this **is not possible in Ubuntu** although in Debian it was possible...

Answer (score 0):

You can try asking pulseaudio to select a different port for the sink (sink is pulseaudio parlance for something where audio "goes").

I suggest you install `pavucontrol`, it will let you select a specific port, instead of just relying on what the kernel auto-selects for you.

This could potentially be automated by adding a short script with pactl to your startup programs list, the script would do something like:

```
pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-speaker
```

Comment: installed `pavucontrol` and it's strange but when I select speakers and unplug headphones there is still no sound but when I have headphones plugged in and change to speakers the sound in headphones gets louder. What's more sound control displays only HDMI port and Headphones (image link: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5827/zrzutekranuz20120814221.png)

And that command gave me this:
`dawid@phoenix:~$ pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-speakers

Failure: No such entity

dawid@phoenix:~$`

Comment: The command may be different based on your sink configuration, if you like you can run `pactl list sinks` and put the output in a pastebin (http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and I can give you an updated version. It will potentially do the same as `pavucontrol` so I can't guarantee it'll work :(

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1149199/
But what interests me is the `State: SUSPENDED`

Comment: ok `pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-speaker` should work. State: SUSPENDED just means the sink is not playing any audio at the moment, start watching a youtube video and you'll see that change to RUNNING.

Comment: pavucontrol shows speakers... but still no sound :/ only in headphones